# How to implement NOTIN operator with Solr

Tags: solr, notin

I am trying to find the documents which hit this example:

q=text:"credit" NOTIN "credit card"

for that query I want to get all the documents which contain the term "credit" but not as part of the phrase "credit card".

so:

1. I don't want to get the documents which include just "credit card".
2. I want to get the documents which include just "credit".
3. I want to get the documents which include "credit" but not as part of credit card.

for example:

doc1 text: "I want to buy with my credit in my card"

doc2 text: "I want to buy with my credit in my credit card"

doc3 text: "I want to buy with my credit card"

The documents returned should be:

doc1, doc2

I can't find nothing about NOTIN operator implementation in SOLR docs.

Comment: `text:credit -text:"credit card"`?

Comment: Why not just not ? ;) As Mats suggested, you need to match documents that contains in their 'text' field the term "credit" but not the *phrase* "credit card". Did you try it ? It should work, provided that your 'text' field analyser is precise enough to make a pf match with slope of 0 (because otherwise the phrase "credit card" could match both "credit in my card" and "credit in my credit card" with a slope > 2)

Comment: thanks guys, but  text:credit -text:"credit card"~0 return just doc1 :(